# Why does producer reacquire the conditional thread almost entirely in my example?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, locks

Here is my example, but if you look at the output

```
 #condition

import threading
C = threading.Condition()
import time
items = []


def consumer():
    while True:
        print(" PRE consumer acquire")
        C.acquire()
        print(" POST consumer acquired")
        if len(items) == 0:
            print(" consumer waiting")
            C.wait() 
        print("consumed and RELEASED")
        C.release()

def producer():
    while True:
        C.acquire()
        print("producer acquired")
        print("product created")
        items.append(1)
        items.append(2)

        C.notify() #notify will unblock the wait, and 
        print("notified")
        time.sleep(1)
        C.release()





t = threading.Thread(target = consumer)
t2 = threading.Thread(target = consumer)
t3 = threading.Thread(target = producer)


t.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()
```

output:

```
PRE consumer acquire PRE consumer acquire
>>> producer acquired


product created
notified
producer acquired
product created
notified
producer acquired
product created
notified
producer acquired
product created
notified
producer acquired
product created
notified
producer acquired
product created
notified
producer acquired
product created
notified
producer acquired
product created
notified
producer acquired
product created
```

As you can see the producer thread is almost entirely acquiring the conditional, despite having two consumer threads. It seems the consumer threads are stuck right before C.acquire(), meaning they aren't acquiring the lock.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

UPDATE:

Following Solomon's advice I have changed (commented out the print statements in between acquire and release) the code:

```
#condition

import threading
C = threading.Condition()
import time
items = []


def consumer():
    while True:
        #print(" PRE consumer acquire") 
        #time.sleep(1)
        C.acquire()
        print(" POST consumer acquired")
        if len(items) == 0:
            print(" consumer waiting")
            C.wait() 
        print("consumed and RELEASED")
        C.release()

def producer():
    while True:
        #time.sleep(1)
        C.acquire()   
        print("producer acquired")
        print("product created")
        items.append(1)

        C.notify() #notify will unblock the wait, and 
        #print("notified")

        C.release()
```

OUTPUT:

```
POST consumer acquired
 consumer waiting
 POST consumer acquired
 consumer waiting
producer acquired
product created
producer acquired
product created
producer acquired
product created
producer acquired
product created
producer acquired
product created
producer acquired
product created
producer acquired
product created
producer acquired
product created
producer acquired
product created
producer acquired
product created
producer acquired
product created
producer acquired
product created
producer acquired
product created
producer acquired
product created
producer acquired
product created
producer acquired
product created
producer acquired
product created
producer acquired
product created
producer acquired
product created
producer acquired
product created
producer acquired
product created
producer acquired
product created
producer acquired
product created
producer acquired
```

Comment: The _very next thing_ that the loop in your `producer()` function does after it releases the condition is, it acquires it again. Notice how that's different from your `consumer()` function, which prints a message in between releasing and attempting to re-acquire.  Printing typically will _block_ the calling thread for a brief moment, and that affords other threads the opportunity to run. Nothing in your `producer()` gives other threads any chance at running in between the release and the re-acquisition of the condition.

Comment: P.S., Don't call `sleep()` while holding a lock. The only time that's a good idea is when you're writing a demo to prove why it is _not_ a good idea.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Ah I see. That makes sense.  However removing the print statement  `#print(" PRE consumer acquire")` and `sleep() `function I still seem to be getting some strange behavior. I still seem to be getting similar behavior. I will update the OP and save the shell output.

Comment: @SolomonSlow   I have updated the code (see UPDATE OP) per your advice, but I still seem to be running into the same problem. I hope I am not making another embarrassing mistake (sorry to bother you).

Comment: Re, `C.notify() #notify will unblock the wait, and...`, Not true.  Notifying a condition does not unblock a waiting thread. It only changes what the thread is waiting for.  Before the `C.notify()` call your `consumer` is awaiting notification. After the notification is delivered, the `C.wait()` call still must wait to re-acquire the lock. When your producer thread releases the lock, it starts a race to see which thread will acquire it next. But the consumer is starting from a 'blocked' state, while the producer starts from an already running state.  The producer always wins that race.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Thanks, yeah those were personal notes that when fully expanded go into the bit about the re-acquiring the lock. It was just easier for me to understand as two "blocks."

As for always winning the race, is there a way to tell how far behind the consumer is from the producer when trying to obtain the conditional lock. Maybe some sort of tool?